# I want my code to convert into lambda / linq expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

```
if (resourceinfo != null && resourceinfo.Products != null)
{
    foreach (var product in resourceinfo.Products)
    {
        if (product.relatedEntities != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < product.relatedEntities.Length; i++)
            {
                if (product.relatedEntities[i].reference.Equals("CONT1234"))
                {
                    if (product.resources != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in product.resources)
                        {
                            if (item.resource != null && item.resource.resourceCharacteristics != null)
                            {
                                for (int j = 0; j < item.resource.resourceCharacteristics.Length; j++)
                                {
                                    var ele = item.resource.resourceCharacteristics;
                                    if (ele[j].name.ToLower().Contains(IMEI_VALUE_NAME))
                                    {
                                        imeiNo = respObj.resourceCharacteristics[0].value = ele[j].value;
                                        break; 
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

I want this to be in lambda expression or linq query format. When I try to bind into lambda expression whenever there is null or empty then an error shows up:

> instance of an object is not defined

Comment: Not everything needs to be LINQ. If you have tried to convert this to LINQ and there was a problem, you should show your working.

Comment: I don't think you need LINQ here but you definitely need to refactor your code. My suggestion is to define more methods to handle each object type.

Comment: Are you really doing a double assignment `imeiNo = respObj.resourceCharacteristics[0].value = ele[j].value` or is this meant to be something else?

Comment: The variables `imeiNo` & `respObj` are not defined anywhere. It makes it a little harder to know what to do here.

Answer (score 1):

your question is not super clear, but the best query I could get is this:

```
var query =
(
    from product in resourceinfo?.Products ?? Enumerable.Empty<Product>().Take(1)
    from relatedEntity in product?.relatedEntities
    where relatedEntity.reference.Equals("CONT1234")
    from item in product?.resources.Take(1)
    from ele in item?.resource?.resourceCharacteristics
    where ele.name.ToLower().Contains(IMEI_VALUE_NAME)
    select ele.value
).Take(1);
```

Comment: thanks Enigmativity.. you made my day ....really u are genius man ....thankss again